# How to Make hardcoded (x,y) coordinates generic for different screens?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, screen, android-custom-view

i have a custom view of `width = 500dpi` and `height = 600dpi` , and i have drawn a point at `(x = 230 ,y = 300)` both are taken from MotionEvent.getX() , MotionEvent.getY() ,within `onTouchEvent()` of custom view.This coordinate is actually a point drawn on canvas of custom view.

Now how can i make this coordinates generic for different screen.So that i can store `(x = 230 ,y = 300)` these points and use them again in future on different screens ?

Comment: I f you just want to store these points so that even after app closes you can use again for the next time , you can use **SharedPreferences**

Comment: i know how to store them , i want to make them generic for multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it by storing coordinates as ratio.

First, you get width and height of the View:

```
int viewWidth = view.getWidth();   // ex. 500dpi in your explanation
int viewHeight = view.getHeight(); // ex. 600dpi in your explanation
```

Second, you convert x-y coordinates to ratio from the upper-left corner of screen:

```
double pointX = (double) MotionEvent.getX() / viewWidth;
double pointY = (double) MotionEvent.getY() / viewHeight;
```

Then, store these **pointX** and **pointY**.

Comment: viewWidth , viewHeight  of custom view, i cannot get them in main activity .

Comment: @Bad Computer Those values are not real names of Android API. For example they are 500 (the width of the view) and 600 (the height of the view) in your explanation.

Comment: can please explain you answer , by example ? i can't seem to understand it correctly.

Comment: i understand what you are saying , `X = (x , 500)*screenWidth , Y = (y , 600) * screenHeight` right ? , **its not working** !!

Comment: where is screen size ? , my main problem was to store point for multiple screens !! after getting ratio , as i've already mentioned above , i can't make display the point at the same location as it was on my previous device where i've got that !!